# Knowing which homogeneous equation to assume with nonhomogeneous differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

When it comes to the method of undetermined coefficients, I am having a difficult time figuring out which homogeneous equation to assume when it comes to nonhomogeneous differential equations.

For example, given the equation: $y'''-4y''+3y'=x^2$,

we can find the homogeneous solution by using: $m^3-4m^2+3m=0$

This gives us roots of: $m_1 = 0, m_2=1, m_3=3$

for a homogeneous equation of: $y_h(x)=C_1 + C_2e+C_3e^3$

However,

$y'' + 4y = 0$

with roots of $m=+/-i$

requires a homogeneous equation of: $y_h(x)=C_1cos(2x)+C_2sin(2x)$

How am I supposed to find homogeneous equations of any given nonhomogeneous differential equations using the method of undetermined coefficients? Is this just something I have to remember for each type of nonhomogeneous equation?

Comment: well in both case you have the exponential function...real roots iin the first case and complex roots in the second case

Comment: Okay. And how I supposed to determine my complementary equation in general, for any given differential equation? I don't understand how you're comment helps me answer that

Comment: for a second order linear diff equation you have three cases depend on the discriminant ...real roots complex roots and repeated roots...thats all you have to remember...

Comment: Plus there is a mistake in your question its $m=\pm2i$ $$\implies y=c_1e^{2ix}+c_2e^{-2ix}$$